# Is it possible to deploy WCF and MVC applications to 1 application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, iis, deployment, publish

I have `WCF` application and `MVC` application in 1 solution. When I deploy projects with WCF, I always deployed them like 2 sites. Firstly, I deployed `WCF` application to `IIS`, then `MVC` application and use `WCF's endpoint address`.

My question is that, is it possible **to deploy MVC and WCF applications together, not like 2 separate site?** WCF runs inside ASP application. And in IIS we have 1 site.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Merge WCF application & MVC application together into a single project. If your WCF project contains too many classes you can move them into a class library.

But you must move following items into web application project:

1. Move .svc file into MVC project, this file does all the magic to
   host your WCF service into IIS.
2. Move System.Service Model section of WCF application into MVC
   project.

Answer (score 0):

I done this.. Works well in local...
But When you host it in an IIS or web deploying

add this code in webconfig

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```